Android Studio Won't Open My Application in Emulator
I'm trying to learn Android coding.
I had a simple example running, then Android Studio suggested I update from Gradle 8.7.0 to Gradle 8.7.1. I accepted the prompt, restarted Android Studio, and after that the emulator won't open my application. The emulator starts up, but does not actually load my application. It times out after 5 minutes and I don't see any error messages to indicate what is going wrong.

I invalidated caches to no avail.
I went back to AGP 8.7.0 without success.
I resynced Gradle to no avail.
I uninstalled the emulator and reinstalled it, to no avail.
Rebooting the machine did not fix anything either.
I created a new base project and it won't run in the emulator either.

Reinstalling Android Studio every time it messes up is time consuming and doesn't seem like the right move.
How can I debug what is going on here?
I am using:
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12483815, built on October 10, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 11.0
Kotlin plugin: K2 mode (Beta)
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4060M
Cores: 12
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  i18n.locale=


The emulator images are stored in your home folder, reinstalling the emulator doesn't change them. Try to delete the emulated device and re-create the emulator device instance.

@Robert I deleted the folder for the "Medium Phone" device and reinstalled it with the UI. It did not repopulate the directory I removed. Did I follow the instructions correctly, or did you mean something different?

I was thinking of the commands available in the "Virtual Device Manager" in Android Studio. Deleting the whole image, or just perform a "Wipe data" or "Cold boot" command.

Two major things I misunderstood:

When you go to SDK Manager, select SDK Tools, and force it to install Android Emulator, it does not create a device to run your application on. You have to go to Tools, Device Manager and click the plus button to Add a new device. The emulator is what this device runs on. So that's how I got it back.
The "Android Emulator" in this picture does not install an instance of a device:


I also had to delete the .gradle caches folder C:\Users\kmort\.gradle\caches. It turns out this is different than asking Android Studio to invalidate its own caches via File, Invalidate Caches.


